# Program to find non-repeating values in a two-dimensional array, incorrect answer

Tags: c

The task is to enter the dimension and data into a two dimensional array and determine the number of non repeating numbers. I tried many things so i asked you to give me your instructions or hints(wanna instructions) how to correct my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int protect(int max_size_1 ,int max_size_2 , int current_1,int current_2,const int arr[max_size_1][max_size_2])
{
    for(int f1=0;f1<max_size_1;f1++)
    {
        for(int f2=0;f2<max_size_2;f2++)
        {
            printf("%d---%d\n",arr[current_1][current_2],arr[f1][f2]);
            if((f1!=current_1 && f2!=current_2) && arr[current_1][current_2]==arr[f1][f2])
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
//0-if there are repetitions 1- if no
}

int main()
{
    int i, j, f1, f2, count=1;
//enter the elements of array
        printf("[i][j] = ");
        scanf("%d", &i);
    int arr[i][i];

    for (f1 = 0; f1<i; f1++)
//loop through rows
    {
        for (f2 = 0; f2<i; f2++)
//cycle through columns
        {
        printf("a[%d][%d] = ", f1, f2);
        scanf("%d", &arr[f1][f2]);
        }
    }
    for (f1 = 0; f1<i; f1++)
//loop through rows  
    {
        for (f2 = 0; f2<i; f2++)
//cycle through columns
        {
        if (protect(i,j,f1,f2,arr)==1){
            count++;}
        }
    }
    printf("\n\n%d", count/2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should compile your code with at least some compilation flags to help you out. You have some uninitialized variables..

Comment: I changed it, but it anyway doesn't work

Comment: I don't know if this is an academic/training problem or a real one. In case of real one, first flat the array (reduce the dimensions to 1). You can do playing with pointers and align compilation options (/Zp), or in a classic way (double loop). After, sort the array with a quick sort, ande then use your trick.